# UITableView cell multiline orientation problem

Tags: uitableview, orientation, cell

I was created one small business application.. In my application i used landscape and portrait mode orientation. Here in UITableView cell the multiline does not fit toboth modes...So how can solve this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the autoresizingMask of the UITableView.

You can do that programmatically or, recommended, throught Interface Builder (see "Autosizing" inside the Size Inspector).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply.... I was used autoresizing mask but using UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight it should not fit..